# will limiting dynamic urls with robots.txt improve my SEO ranking?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

My website has about 200 useful articles. Because the website has an internal search function with lots of parameters, the search engines end up spidering urls with all possible permutations of additional parameters such as tags, search phrases, versions, dates etc. Most of these pages are simply a list of search results with some snippets of the original articles.

According to Google's Webmaster-tools Google spidered only about 150 of the 200 entries in the xml sitemap. It looks as if Google has not yet seen all of the content years after it went online.

I plan to add a few "Disallow:" lines to robots.txt so that the search engines no longer spiders those dynamic urls. In addition I plan to disable some url parameters in the Webmaster-tools "website configuration" --> "url parameter" section.

Will that improve or hurt my current SEO ranking? It will look as if my website is losing thousands of content pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) are for. If one page (e.g. article) can be reached by more then one URL then you need to specify the primary URL using a canonical URL. This prevents duplicate content issues and tells Google which URL to display in their search results.

So do not block any of your articles and you don't need to enter any parameters, either. Just use canonical URLs and you'll be fine.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't add a <link rel="canonical" ... > tag because I am running a commercial java application. Also, an internal search result page is not a variant of a single real page.

Comment: Search result pages can't be found by search engines since they do not submit forms. So those pages won't cause you any problems. If you link to search result pages that have query strings then you can try to block them using pattern matching in a robots.txt file or if one page handles the searches just block it via robots.txt. And you should because Google considers those pages to be low quality.

Answer (score 0):

As nn4l pointed out, canonical is not a good solution for search pages.

The first thing you should do is have search results pages include a robots meta tag saying noindex. This will help get them removed from your index and let Google focus on your real content. Google should slowly remove them as they get re-crawled.

Other measures:

In GWMT tell Google to ignore all those search parameters. Just a band aid but may help speed up the recovery.

Don't block the search page in the robots.txt file as this will block the robots from crawling and cleanly removing those pages already indexed. Wait till your index is clear before doing a full block like that.

Your search system must be based on links (a tags) or GET based forms and not POST based forms. This is why they got indexed. Switching them to POST based forms should stop robots from trying to index those pages in the first place. JavaScript or AJAX is another way to do it.